# Forcing ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework) to Compile As x64 rather than Any CPU

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Our project runs on 64bit Windows and we have no intention to target 32bit or non-Intel platform (and no intention to run non-Windows).

I have an ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework) set to AnyCPU and it references other .NET projects that are x64.

**How can I force the ASP.NET Core project to compile as x64 in the Build Configuration? (If I set it, it will reset when I hit save and go back to AnyCPU).**

Having the Core environment as AnyCPU is causing me some CI problems.

Comment: I am having this issue too Adam. It seems I can add "platform":"x64" within the buildOptions of project.json, but visual studio still looks inside bin/debug instead of bin/x64/. Have you had any luck resolving?

Comment: @adam3039 There was no solution...